# Retrieve combination of composite key

Tags: mysql, composite-key

I have

```
id   |   start        |    end
-------------------------------------
213  |   2014-03-20   |    2014-04-01
999  |   2014-03-20   |    2014-04-01
213  |   2012-02-10   |    2013-02-23
```

table is defined with a composite key `(id, start, end)`

I need to read all existing combinations of start & end

e.g.

```
res['start'] | res['end']
-------------------------
2014-03-20   | 2014-04-01
2013-02-10   | 2013-02-23
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want this

```
SELECT DISTINCT `start`,`end` FROM table_name;
```